# Is there an way to transform PSQL data to MONGODB object without concat?

Tags: json, mongodb, postgresql

I'm using mongoDB on my new project, and it got to be filled with my PSQL Data.

So, to receive my *Operation* data I could write this select:

```
select ope_id, ope_value from operation;
```

And to transform into MongoDB (JSON Code), I could try something like this:

```
select '{"operation":' ||row_to_json(record)|| '}'
   from (
       select ope_id, ope_value from operation
   ) as record;
```

And it returns me this:

```
{"operation":{"ope_id":1054,"ope_value":0.00}}
```

But when I've started to use sub-objects, I couldn't find an easier way to concat or create a complex object right on PSQL extraction, like this JSON example:

```
{
  "operation":{ 
    "ope_id":1054,
    "ope_value":0.00
  },
  "_ownedByCred": {
    "cre_id": 1,
    "cre_name": "someName"
  },
  "exampleGroup": {
    "exampleSubGroup": {
      "data1": "teste",
      "data2": "teste",
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The || operator is overloaded.  It can be used to concatenate text, but it can also be used to concatenate JSONB objects.

```
select '{"a":"b"}'::jsonb || '{"c":"d"}'::jsonb;
       ?column?       
----------------------
 {"a": "b", "c": "d"}
```

So just make your objects as jsonb (not json) and concatenate them with `||`.

Of course there many other ways to do it as well.

Also, it would be cleaner to create your initial JSONB objects without building then up textually.

```
select jsonb_build_object('operation', row_to_json(record))
   from (
       select ope_id, ope_value from operation
   ) as record;
```